# How to get all place details from a Place Details Request using Google Places API Web Service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-places-api

I am trying to get data, like phone numbers, from a Place Details Request using The Google Places API Web Service. I am unable to get response data that is similar to the one shown in this [guide](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details#PlaceDetailsResults), even though I'm getting the place id from the same address.

The place id I get is different from the one in the guide. My place id is 'ChIJ8UadyjeuEmsRDt5QbiDg720' and theirs is 'ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4'. If I use their place id I get all the data I need.

The only data I can get are: address_components, adr_address, formatted_address, geometry, icon, id, name, place_id, reference, scope, types, url, and vicinity. How can I get data like a phone number from a request?

```
var placesRequest = $http({
  method: "post",
  url: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=" + <my place id>+"&key=<my key>"
});

placesRequest.success(function (data) {
  console.log("data", data);
});
```

Same problem with Google Maps JavaScript API using this code.

```
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: -33.866, lng: 151.196},
      zoom: 15
  });

  google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

  service.getDetails({
     placeId: $scope.newUserData.address.place_id
  }, function(place, status) {
     if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
       if(place) {
         console.log("place", place);

        }
     }
  });
}
initMap();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phone number is missing in the Google Places API because Google Maps doesn't have a phone number for that particular place.  If you request the details for a place with a phone number on Google Maps, it will be returned.

Take a closer look at ChIJ8UadyjeuEmsRDt5QbiDg720.  It's an office building called "Workplace 6" — notice that the details say it is of type `premise`.  If you visit the Google Maps URL in the `url` field (https://maps.google.com/?q=Workplace+6&ftid=0x6b12ae37ca9d46f1:0x6defe0206e50de0e) you'll notice there's no phone number listed there either.

The other Place ID, ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4, is for one of the businesses located inside that building (Google).  If you compare the `address_components` or `formatted_address` you'll see they don't have quite the same address (Google's address is floor 5 of that building).

In general, any field of a place might be absent.  This happens if Google Maps doesn't know it, or if it simply doesn't apply (e.g. you won't find `opening_hours` on France).  As the documentation for [Place Details Results](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details#PlaceDetailsResults) say:

> Each result **may** contain the following fields:

[Emphasis mine.]

Comment: The library I am using to get the place id in the first place uses the Geocoding service so I think that is the problem. Thanks for pointing out the address differences